# Ant Design - Show Select dropdown when we click button in multiple table rows

Tags: select, antd

I have button with icon and i wanted to display select dropdown when we click on that button, where  i don't want to show input field.
Edge case : I am doing this for multiple component render, where i am using antd table where it contains those button in rows.

I have tried adding open property and handling it in state, but when i click on one button and select dropdown will open but it is not closing on clicking another button in another row.